# Reverse SSH tunnel with putty

Tags: putty, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to set up a reverse ssh tunnel using putty:
I have a dev machine that IT will not open any ports on and I have a spotfire.server.com machine that has open ports.
What I want is the ability for the spotfire.server.com machine to connect to a port on my dev machine. That's the purpose of the tunnel.

I open putty on my dev machine and fill do this:
[image]

What I expect it to do is when I start an http server listening on my dev machine on port 5171 and and http request comes to http://spotfire.server.com:8080 I will get that request on my local dev server, and when I send an http response to that request it will go from me to spotfire.server.com and then to the caller of the port 8080.
As of right now when I click Add and OK on that screen I get a sound that probably means error and nothing else happens. Nothing in event log no log files.
I am probably doing it wrong, but which part?

```
plink -R 8080:localhost:5171 user@spotfire.server.com
```

reports

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
```